# Objectify OfyService NoClassDefFoundError for app engine endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

My android-appengine-endpoint project is setup entirely by android studio. Therefore I don't mess around with anything: I just let android studio add my AppEngine module to my android project. Now I am getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Do I have to set somethings in gradle or configure somethings in android studio to get rid of this error? Basically when I try to test my app I get the exception.

Code:

**Note: Instead of calling `ofy` inside my endpoint class, UserDao is a place where all the `ofy` data access calls are made.** You can compare my code to [this tutorial](http://rominirani.com/2014/08/26/gradle-tutorial-part-9-cloud-endpoints-persistence-android-studio/)

```
public class UserDao extends OfyService {
    public static void persist(User user) {
        ofy().save().entities(user).now();
    }
    public static User getById(long id) {
        return ofy().load().type(User.class).id(id).now();
    }
    public static List<User> getByTwitterId(Long twitterId) {
        return ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("twitterId", twitterId).list();
    }
}

public class OfyService {
    public OfyService() {}

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Food.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Pet.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() { return ObjectifyService.ofy(); }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

The actual error as seen from the App Engine Console:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backed method
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.server.data.dao.UserDao
    at com.mycompany.server.utils.Authenticator.verifyAccount(Authenticator.java:22)
    at com.mycompany.server.endpoint.server.getFood(server.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Every post I see here seem to be talking about `WEB-INF\lib`. Well Android Studio has not created any lib directory inside my WEB-INF. So both Android Studio and App Engine are from Google. Therefore I am at a lost there.

My `webapp/WEB-INF` has only three files in it:

- `web.xml`
- `logging.properties`
- `appengine-web.xml`

Here is an image of my dependencies in case it helps:

[image]

Comment: I write the actual app engine source: entities, endpoints, ofy. I just don't decide what goes inside `WEB-INF`. As for UserDao, it is an OfyService subclass, not an entity. So I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: The only difference with UserDao (vs the other OfyService subclasses) is that one of its static methods throw an exception: `IllegalStateException`

Comment: UserDao is **not** an entity. It does not have the `@Entity` annotation. By subclass I mean `public class UserDao extends OfyService` where OfyService is simply a wrapper for `ObjectifyService`, I am simply following the best practice recommended structure.

Comment: I refactor the UserDao class and remove the Exception. That did it. I was having one of the satic methods throw an exception in a certain case. That was the cause of the problem.

Comment: In the stack-trace I see `com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter`, and I conclude that Gradle has downloaded Objectify without problems. What class is missing then?

Comment: If I remove UserDao and use OfyService directly, I still get the NoClassDefFoundError except this time it's for OfyService (of course). So really the problem is with Objectify setup.  And @naXa, I was able to verify that the jars are indeed downloaded to `.../build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: It seems that it's failing during class initialization - most likely a static block of `UserDao`.

Comment: Could you debug the static block and tell where does it fail?

Comment: I remove the UserDao class and directly use the OfyService class and I still get the error. And the OfyService is exactly what the docs say I am supposed to use. I will step through it. And see if I get more specific insight, if that's what you mean by debug. I have posted the entire OfyService code and the entire UserDao code. There isn't much to step-through there, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: What kind of HTTP request is causing that stack trace to occur? A Cloud Endpoints API call? A normal request?

Comment: Cloud Endpoint call from android phone.

Comment: I have added an image of all my dependencies, in case it helps. Maybe they are interfering with each other somehow, I don't really know.

Comment: I break the static method into pieces, and the crash happens when I call `OfyService.ofy()`

Comment: When you call `ofy()` method for the first time, the static block that registers classes executes. Does it fail to register any class?

Comment: @naXa inside the static registration block, I place a logging before all registrations and a logging after all registrations. The before line is printed, the after line is not.

Comment: after days of trying to get this bug to go away, I seem to be the one going away. Many thanks to everyone for trying to help. I will start recoding my server using the datastore native api instead of objectify. Thanks for all the support.

Answer (score 1):

As I find out from our discussion Objectify fails to register classes for an unknown reason.

Perhaps,

1. you have incorrect annotations on one of your data classes (provide a source code of `User`, `Food`, `Pet` for further investigation);
2. or call `OfyService` methods from another thread at the same time (which is unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Cloud Endpoint, do this:

1. In your Endpoint class, create a constructor.
2. In the constructor, call `new OfyService()`.

The reason this may work is that you will have loaded all your objectify related classes way way before you need to use them (i.e. way before a client makes a first call). Right now you are loading them right before you need them . And delays in the App-Engine class loader may be what's killing you. The sad thing is, the structure you are using is very popular and so most people use it that way: and yet there is no guarantee that it will always work. It's a race condition thing. App-engine can be very slow to load classes. Lucky (or unlucky) for you, you find the problem early. People should give you some upvotes for your pains :).

Comment: At least you're properly feeding your garbage collector since this solution creates an OfyService object just for it ;-).

Comment: It is an interesting concept, sci-fi-ishly speaking: An entity that exist as a mere catalyst, nothing more.